# Renaming Excel Worksheets without updating references

Tags: vba, excel

Let's say I have a excel workbook to create reports on weekly base. The workbook consists of three worksheets, named

- `Compare`: Comparison of current week and last week (in reality, this are 20 sheets with diagramms)
- `New_Data`: Data for this week
- `Old_Data`: Data from week before

I get the weekly data as another excel workbook, coping the one sheet into my workbook and do the comparison. It would be find to just:

1. delete the sheet `Old_Data`
2. rename the sheet `New_Data` into `Old_Data`
3. copy the sheet from the other workbook and rename it `New_Data`

I already managed to build all of this in VBA, including a handy file dialogue to import the new data. No big deal after all..

But if I rename a sheet, Excel is clever enough to notice and changes every reference in `Compare` to the new name.

Is there a way do this renaming in VBA or do I have to update every single reference?

Comment: Why don't you just copy the data into the relevant sheets instead of replacing the whole sheet?

Comment: @Rory: I don't like you guys.. 
That works, I solved it that way now, to keep things going. Like ever, many roads.. 
BTW, I would like to credit you, but that is not a answer.. therefore, I can't. Up to you to write it as answer, even if it is more a "workaround"